# Как сконвертировать проект на node js в статичный сайт без бекенда?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node.js

Изначально сайт разрабатывался на node js и react, но купленный хостинг для сайта поддерживает только статиные сайты на html/css/js без бэка. Можно ли каким-то образом сделать из сайта на node статичный сайт, и если да, то как это сделать проще всего?

Comment: Если бэк взаимодействует с БД, то ближе к никак. Я бы рекомендовал хостера поменять!

Comment: Бэк не взаимодействует с БД, по факту сайт и так статичный, а node и react использовались для удобства написания сайта

Comment: А что делает node для сайта? Статику отдает?

Comment: Да, он нужен исключительно для статики, полноценного бэка нет

Comment: Ну так а в чем тогда проблема? Разместите на хостинге ваш хтмл, цсс и жс в правильных папках и наслаждайтесь

Comment: Так у нас все в одном файле. Даже html нет, вернее не в одном файле, а все на js

Comment: Мы же react используем

Comment: Реакт билдится в html, css, js. Без html вы бы в браузере ничего не увидели бы... да и нода с реактом в 1 файле жить не сможет, если это только не nextjs и у ввс все живет на бэке

Comment: Наверняка есть какая нибудь команда yarn build которая отдаст вам папку с скомпиленным в js, HTML, CSS кодом.